# What causes an Assertion failed error in openCV?

Tags: python, opencv, face-detection

The error I get while debugging on IDLE python (3.7) is:

```
  cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.3) (some directory files)
- error : (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cvtColor'
```

The program itself is taken from a website:

```py
import cv2

import numpy as np

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('C:\Program Files\Python38\Lib\site-packages\cv2\data\haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml')

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor=1.5, minNeighbors=5)

    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        print(x,y,w,h)
        roi_gray = gray[y:y + h, x:x + w]  # (ycord_start, ycord_end)
        roi_color = frame[y:y + h, x:x + w]
        img_item = 'my-image.png'
        cv2.imwrite(img_item,roi_gray)
        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        color = (0,0,255)
        stroke = 2
        width = x + w
        height = y + h
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
    if cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

So I would like to know what is causing this error.

Comment: Either `VideoCapture` failed to open the camera, or the `read` failed for some reason -- your code doesn't handle either of those scenarios.

Comment: Hello, thank you for replying, I tried the program on my computer (which runs using Windows) and it was functionnal. But the actual problem is when I tried to implement it on a raspberry PI 4 while using exactly the same program that's when I get this error.
I believe that VideoCapture fails to open the camera as you said, is there any solution to that ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
```

In fact 0 is the id of the opened video capturing device (i.e. a camera index). I imagine that the program can't detect any camera and thus it throws this error. You can check if video capturing has been initialized already by printing cap.isOpened() befor the loop, if it is false, then you have a problem in initializing the video capturing.

Regards

Comment: So before the program itself I should write :
if (cap.isOpened() == False) :
   print("Camera doesn't work")
Something similar to it ?

Comment: Yes, something like that, it is more like  "video capturing hasn't been initialized", but just check out it is the output of "cap.isOpened()", just to check if this is really the problem.